# What do you call someone who uses equipment made by someone else to run a business?

Tags: word-request

Suppose that I acquired the rights to run a little booth in a theme park for selling ice creams to kids. I cannot run my business if I don't have the machine that makes ice cream, so I buy one of these machines and start earning money.

I am not the "manufacturer" of the machine, I probably got it from a "reseller". What word describes the fact that I use this machine to run my business? I am looking for more specific word that "final user". (I am looking for the equivalent of the French word "exploitant", if this helps)

Comment: It depends on the legal/commercial relationship.  You could be a **franchisee** if you have a particular kind of license to use the brand name in your concession stand.

Comment: I think the word you mentioned, *final user*, would be fine. I'm more familiar with *end user*, though.

Comment: In Romance languages, one says the equivalent of "how do you call," but in English we say "what do you call." Also, equipment is rarely a count noun. If you wanted, you could day "a piece of equipment."

Comment: Please define **exploitant** as you understand it, and maybe you'll get some better answers. Your question is not very clear or precise. "What word describes the fact that I use this machine to run my business? "

Comment: Particularly how exploitant is different from opérateur.

Comment: You didn't milk the cows that gave the milk that made the cream that... Well, you see where this is going. No-one is responsible for *every* link in a commercial supply chain. But unless you're the kid who finally *eats* the ice-cream, you're just a *trader* (hopefully, adding *value* beyond your profit). What about a group of four kids who send one of their number to get the ice-creams? He's part of the supply chain too! :)

Comment: @TRomano : I'm not even sure that a word exists in English, or that even the notion is worth being granted a word. "operator" seems to fit best sofar. But the "operator" to me seems to be the user on the field, whether she's me, or one of my employees. But I am the owner of the business, and this machine is critical to my business. No machine, no ice cream business. I can deliver (or have delivered by my employee) ice cream and make profit even if I don't have a clue of what ice cream is made of. The "operator" just has to load the machine with premixed ingredients and smile to customers.

Comment: @AlanCarmack : you're right. I meant "a piece of equipment".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That kid is a "stooge", right ? :)

Comment: @Laurent LA RIZZA:  Since virtually all businesses use some equipment made by someone else, there's little need for a noun to describe such a business.  But if there's one main piece of equipment on which the business depends (the coffee shop's espresso machine, the ice-cream stand's swirly cone machine, the sawmill's rip saw) then maybe there could be a word for that, especially if there's only one manufacturer of the machine (the competitors all having gone out of business, say); we might call such a business a **captive user**.

Comment: But you seem to be looking for a name for the sort of business where no skill is needed to produce the product, because it relies on some "automatic" feature of the equipment it uses, like a Starbucks coffee shop which uses so-called "superautomatic" espresso machines versus the kind of machine where the barista must employ some skill and technique in setting the granularity of the coffee and the dosing and packing of the portafilter.

Comment: @TRomano : That's exactly what I am looking for. The Starbucks thing.

Answer (score 1):

The final owner of any product is usually the "[end user](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/end+user)".

Answer (score 0):

In the chain you have described:

You are a **client** of the distributor of the machine that you use and possibly the manufacturer of the machine if you have a maintenance contract with them.

You are also an **end user** of the machine, in that you are the one who actually uses it, which also makes you an **operator** of the machine.  The manufacturer of your machine would be interested in how well their machine works for you.

By analogy, in the computer world, the person who uses the computer is considered the *end user*, and there is where the focus usually lies when referring to "user experience".

You are a **manufacturer** of ice cream, since you intake raw materials and assemble them into your finished product.

Your *clients* or *end users* or *customers* (they will be one and the same for you) are the the people that eat your ice cream product.